# How can you link a Rust library with a C app into one WASM file using Emscripten?

Tags: rust, build, emscripten

I have [a project](https://github.com/curiousdannii/emglken) that links a C library with a C app using Emscripten. I would like to replace the C library with a library written in Rust. How can this be accomplished?

I know that there are two relevant WASM targets in Rust, the normal `wasm32-unknown-unknown` one and the `wasm32-unknown-emscripten` one. I'm guessing the latter target is necessary for it to work with the Emscripten compiler? But how do I tell Emscripten to use a .wasm library rather than a .a library?

There may be other ways of linking Rust and C code together into a .wasm but I think I do need to stick with Emscripten as I require its Asyncify feature (and in the future will use its WASMFS system too.)

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: @JayMcCarthy I asked about it here: https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/discussions/17294 The Emscripten team say it should be possible, but the specific details still need to be worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually quite straightforward!

So first, make sure your Rust project is set to build a static library:

```ini
[lib]
crate-type=["staticlib"]
```

Then compile your Rust project with the correct target, `wasm32-unknown-emscripten`:

```bash
cargo build --target=wasm32-unknown-emscripten
```

Then you can simply link the static lib into your C/C++ app. Note that you'll probably want to use a variable to handle the different paths for dev and release builds. I'm using CMake:

```
if (${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} STREQUAL Release)
    set(REMGLK_RS_LIB_FOLDER ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/remglk/target/wasm32-unknown-emscripten/release)
else()
    set(REMGLK_RS_LIB_FOLDER ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/remglk/target/wasm32-unknown-emscripten/debug)
endif()

target_link_libraries(app_target ${REMGLK_RS_LIB_FOLDER}/libremglk_capi.a)
```

Lastly, I needed to change the linker language to C++, as otherwise using `panic!()` seems to result in exception errors when the final app is only C, not C++. Depending on what features of Rust you use this may not be necessary.

```
set_target_properties(app_target PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```